# PHP object to a class method

Tags: php, oop

I have class **FieldFile** which use object **Image** in method *save*

```
namespace wti\Model;
use wti\Image;

class FieldFile
{
    public function save(Image $image, array $files): void
    {...}
}
```

But when I use this method in other class:

```
namespace wti;
use wti\Image;
use wti\Model\FieldFile;

    class MainWI
    {
        public function load()
        {
            $loader = new FieldFile();
            $loader->save($_FILES);
            // or $loader->save(Image, $_FILES);

        }
    }
```

I get error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to wti\Model\FieldFile::save() must be an instance of wti\Image

Help me, where my code is wrong?

P.S. Image is the abstract class.

Comment: First argument passed to `save()` method should be of type `wti\Image`

Comment: 'Image is the abstract class' - where is it used?

Comment: Class Image uses in FieldFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the Image instance to save function in FieldFile class.
have look at the code below.

```
namespace wti\Model;
use wti\Image;

class FieldFile
{
   public function save(Image $image, array $files): void
   {...}
}

namespace wti;
use wti\Image;
use wti\Model\FieldFile;

class MainWI
{
    public function load()
    {
        // here you should create the image instance like
        $image = new Image();
        $loader = new FieldFile();
        //$loader->save($_FILES);
        $loader->save($image, $_FILES);

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, and I will do it. But tell me how I can implement DI in this code?

Answer (score 1):

don't you need to send in an Image argument before the Files argument:

```
$loader->save($Image, $_FILES);
```

or else change the save method too:

```
save(array $files)
```

and instantiate the image in save.

Comment: Thanks for your answer